# How to select an element inside a dom-module in polymer 1.0?

Tags: dom, polymer-1.0

I have the following dom-module that I am trying to create interactions for.

```
<dom-module is="bw-image-upload">
<template>
  <vaadin-upload  id="uploader"
                  target="{{ API_URL}}/images/upload"
                  method="POST"
                  max-files="1"
                  max-file-size="200000"
                  accept="image/*"
                  upload-success="uploadResponseHandler"
                  file-reject="errorHandler"
  >
  </vaadin-upload>
</template>
  <script>
      Polymer({
                is: 'bw-image-upload',
                properties: {
                      image: String,
                      notify: true
                }
              });

      var uploader = document.querySelector('#uploader');

      uploader.addEventListener('upload-before', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
      });

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I want to select the vaadin-upload element by it's ID but it returns a null and I am confused on why it is returning null.

How do I select an element like this in Polymer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element has an id and is statically added to the template, you can use

```
var uploader = this.$.uploader;
```

to get a reference to an element with the id `uploader`.

If the element is inside `<template is="dom-if">`, `<template is="dom-repeate">` or otherwise dynamically created this is not supported.

In such cases you can use

```
var uploader = this.$$('#uploader');
```

`this.$$(...)` provides full CSS selector support and returns the first matching element, while `this.$...` only supports IDs.

Comment: Thanks, Gunter. I forgot to check up on the question but i started using this.$.id to get the element. Thanks for your reply.